# Merging generic method

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression

I'm new to C# and I have the following 3 methods. These methods allow the caller to retrieve differents properties of the table by specifying a lambda expression on the given method.  However, I have the feeling an expert would combine them even further into a single generic method. If this is possible, please let me know how.

```
private KeyValuePair<T, int> GetHeaderProperty<T>(Func<Header, T> Property, 
                                                  Source ds)
{
    Func<Source, Header> GetValue =
        a => Books.Where(str => str.BookId == a.DiscardBookId)
                 .First().Header;
    return new KeyValuePair<T,int>(Property(GetValue(ds)), 0);
} 

private KeyValuePair<T, int> GetBookProperty<T>(Func<Book, T> Property,
                                               Source ds)
{
    Func<Source, Book> GetValue = 
        a => Books.Where(str => str.BookId == a.DiscardBookId).First();

    return new KeyValuePair<T, int>(Property(GetValue(ds)), 0);
} 

private KeyValuePair<T, int> GetFleetProperty<T>(Func<Fleet, T> Property,
                                                 Source ds)
{
    Func<Source,Fleet> GetValue =
        a => Books.Where(str => str.BookId == a.DiscardBookId).First()
                 .Header.Fleet;

    return new KeyValuePair<T,int>(Property(GetValue(ds)), 0);
}
```

Comment: An _expert would combine them even furether into a single generic method_: which result do you want to obtain?

Comment: Please investigate my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will be equivalent to calling all three methods in a row and adding the results to a list:

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>> GetFleetProperty<T>(
                                              Func<Book, T> PropertyBook,
                                              Func<Header, T> PropertyHeader,
                                              Func<Fleet, T> PropertyFleet,
                                              Source ds)
{
    Func<Source,Fleet> GetValue =
        a => Books.Where(str => str.BookId == a.DiscardBookId).First();

    var book = GetValue(ds);
    var result = new List<KeyValuePair<T, int>>();
    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<T, int>(PropertyBook(book), 0);
    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<T, int>(PropertyHeader(book.Header), 0);
    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<T, int>(PropertyFleet(book.Header.Fleet), 0);
    return result;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
You could also create a method like this:

```
private KeyValuePair<T, int> GetProperty<T, TProperty>(
                                 Func<TProperty, T> Property, 
                                 Func<Book, TProperty> GetProperty, 
                                 Source ds)
{
    Func<Source, Header> GetValue =
        a => Books.Where(str => str.BookId == a.DiscardBookId)
                 .First();
    var book = GetValue(ds);
    return new KeyValuePair<T,int>(Property(GetProperty(book)), 0);
}
```

You would call it like this for Header:

```
GetProperty(xyz, b => b.Header, ds);
```

You would call it like this for Book:

```
GetProperty(xyz, b => b, ds);
```

You would call it like this for Fleet:

```
GetProperty(xyz, b => b.Header.Fleet, ds);
```

Comment: thanks Daniel, i will call each of these method several times to get  differents properties accross these tables and i do not really want to return a the list all these times. I'm aware i did not explain this accurately. as an example, the first method mayve be called 15 time, the next one 7 times and so on....

Comment: @Paul: So, maybe its a good idea to explain it now? After your comment, it's completely unclear how those methods should be merged.

Comment: i just did above. each method will be called several time on the a specif table... Like Book, Header, Fleet etc...  Maybe what i#m trying to do may not just be possible... thank you for having a look anyway

Comment: Excellent, this looks like what i was looking for. I will run it and let you know.... thousands thanks Paul

Answer (score 1):

You can use some thing like this

```
public interface IPieceProvider<T>
    {
        T GetPiece();
    }

    public class Fleet
    {
        public string Test;
    }

    public class Header
    {
        public Fleet Fleet;
        public string Test;
    }

    public class Source
    {
        public int DiscardBookId;
    }

    public partial class Book
        : IPieceProvider<Book>, IPieceProvider<Header>, IPieceProvider<Fleet>
    {
        public int BookId;
        public Header Header;
        public string Test;

        Book IPieceProvider<Book>.GetPiece()
        {
            return this;
        }

        Header IPieceProvider<Header>.GetPiece()
        {
            return Header;
        }

        Fleet IPieceProvider<Fleet>.GetPiece()
        {
            return Header.Fleet;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        Book[] Books;

        private KeyValuePair<T, int> GetProperty<T, TP>(Func<TP, T> propertyGetter, Source ds)
        {
            return Books
                .Where(b => b.BookId == ds.DiscardBookId)
                .Cast<IPieceProvider<TP>>()
                .Select(p => p.GetPiece())
                .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<T, int>(propertyGetter(p), 0))
                .First();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var source = new Source();
            var prg = new Program();
            var bookTest = prg.GetProperty((Book b) => b.Test, source);
            var headerTest = prg.GetProperty((Header h) => h.Test, source);
            var fleetTest = prg.GetProperty((Fleet f) => f.Test, source);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Viacheslav , this looks really beautifull. I particulary like the more simple call.  Cheers paul

Comment: Hi Viacheslav ,     public interface IPieceProvider<T>
    where T : Book, Header, Fleet
{
    T GetPiece();  does not compile.
}  the class type constraint 'UserQuery.Header' must come before any other constraints

Comment: I publish fixed version of sample, try it please

Comment: Hi Viacheslav, i have not tried the code but i can see a potential problem. Book is already defined as i have used linq to sql and it provides a definition for the entity Book. with that in mind, do you think redefined Book will work?

Comment: Each entity generated class marked as partial you can extend it without any problem. My code was modified to reflect that change.